# various ways to improve performance of procedure

Tags: sql, oracle, performance, plsql, query-optimization

Oracle provides DBMS_PROFILER and DBMS_HPROF tools for profiling PL/SQL.Is there any alternative way for profiling other than this

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take few moments to take a [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and also read [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) to get better answers for your questions

Comment: Profilers don't improve the performance of our code: they show us where the program spends its time, so we can identify bottlenecks and prioritize our tuning activity. So it's not clear what you are asking. Do you want alternative ways to probe your code? Or do you want advice on the sorts of things you could do to make it run faster. If you don't ask a clear question you won't get a helpful response.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you should be looking into what your procedure is actually doing ? If there are lot of unnecessary checks or DMLS.
[Oracle Performance Tuning Notes](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B13789_01/appdev.101/b10807/12_tune.htm)